# Java: display results from a different class put into textbox applet

Tags: java, textbox, boolean, jtextarea

I'm currently learning the basics of Java and am having trouble with displaying results from another class file into a TextArea within a different class file.

The first file has a boolean structure where values are currently false, and as the user clicks a button, the values will turn true.

FirstFile:

```
public class roll{
boolean bool[] = {true, false, false, false};
```

Second file: Has an applet that displays a TextArea and a button.

```
public class Text extends Applet{
TextArea tA = new TextArea(" ", 10, 10);
Button btn = new Button("Click to display string");

public void init(){
add(tA);
```

When all the values in the first file turn out to be true, what method can I use to show the message in the TextArea?

Answer (score 1):

You have method `append(String)` at TextArea. Ex: `tA.append(bool[0] + "\n");`

**Edit:**

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

```
mybutton.addActionListener(new NameClass());
//-----//
class NameClass implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        //Your Actions
        tA.append("text \n");

    }
}
```

Comment: How can I implement a button that runs that method ^?